# Does Cycles X automatically apply to old projects?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm hesitant to ask this since it may be a rather trivial question, but after downloading Blender 3.0 I can't help but feel like there's something off when it comes to rendering in comparison between brand new .blend files and old ones.

I feel like there's some setting that I have to change in the old files for the render to be faster, but I haven't found anything online talking about it.

Maybe I've missed the whole point and Cycles X in only available in a branch option, but I'm pretty sure all of the features talked about in the [Reel Showcase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRqY_20ti9A) are included in the stable version Blender 3.0, the one you download without going experimental.

Comment: I think Cycles X is now part of Blender 3, it's available if you simply select Cycles as render engine

Comment: I've just opened a fairly complex scene created in 2.93 in 3.0 and compared the rendering speeds without changing anything at all. 2.93 took 1 minute 32 seconds to render the image whereas 3.0 takes 41 seconds. So, yes, it's somewhat faster with no settings changes at all! :^)) If I had a GPU which could use OptiX rendering it would be faster still...